# Configure Log4J to exclusively output logs to unique files for each instance of class

Tags: java, log4j

I have a class "SomeClass" with its own log4j logger. 
I'll have very few instances of Someclass in my program. 
How do I configure Log4j to exclusively output logs to unique files for each instance of my class.

```
public class SomeClass {
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SomeClass.class);

private final String name;  
public SomeClass(String name) throws Exception{
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

```
public class MainClass{ 
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    // logs generated by this instance should only go to a file AAA_YYYYMMDD.log
    SomeClass instance1 = new SomeClass("AAA");  
    // logs generated by this instance should only go to a file BBB_YYYYMMDD.log
    SomeClass instance2 = new SomeClass("BBB");
}
```

}

Comment: Which version of log4j?

Comment: I believe this can only be achieved programmatically. This question has already been asked and there is an answer with a link to a solution.